# How to generate a new arithmetic exercise in a quiz game

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, math, text

I'm writing a Python math game in which the program asks an addition question and the user has to get the right answer to continue. My question is, how can I make the program generate a new math problem when the user gets the last one correct?

```
import random

firstNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
secondNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
result = firstNumber + secondNumber
result = int(result)
print("Hello ! What\'s your name ? ")
name = input()
print("Hello !"+" "+ name)
print("Ok !"+" "+ name +" "+ "let\'s start !")
print("What is"+ " " + str(firstNumber) +"+"+ str(secondNumber))
userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
while (True) :
    if (userAnswer == result):
        print("Correct")
        print("Good Job!")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong\n")
        userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
input("\n\n Press to exit")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the game with a pair of nested loops. In the outer loop, generate a new arithmetic problem. In the inner loop, keep asking the user for guesses until he either gives the right answer or decides to quit by entering a blank line.

```
import random

playing = True

while playing:
    # Generate a new arithmetic problem.
    a = random.randint(1, 50)
    b = random.randint(1, 50)
    solution = a + b
    print('\nWhat is %d + %d? (to quit, enter nothing)' % (a, b))

    # Keep reading input until the reply is empty (to quit) or the right answer.
    while True:
        reply = input()
        if reply.strip() == '':
            playing = False
            break
        if int(reply) == solution:
            print('Correct. Good job!')
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong. Try again.')

print('Thank you for playing. Goodbye!')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. The `getnumbers()` returns two random numbers, just like in your script. Now just add in you game code. Let me know if you have questions!

```
import random

def getnumbers():
    a = random.randint(1, 50)
    b = random.randint(1, 50)
    return a, b

print("Math Game!")

while True:
    a, b = getnumbers()

    # game code goes here
    print("%d %d" % (a, b))

    input()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
 import random

def make_game():
    firstNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
    secondNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
    result = firstNumber + secondNumber
    result = int(result)
    print("What is"+ " " + str(firstNumber) +"+"+ str(secondNumber))
    userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
    while (True) :
        if (userAnswer == result):
            print("Correct")
            print("Good Job!")
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong\n")
            userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))

print("Hello ! What\'s your name ? ")
name = input()
print("Hello !"+" "+ name)
print("Ok !"+" "+ name +" "+ "let\'s start !")

while True:
    make_game()
    end = input('\n\n Press to "end" to exit or "enter" to continue: ')
    if end.strip() == 'end':
        break
```